# disable ascii art in Ubuntu installation process

Tags: 16.04, system-installation

When installing Ubuntu from console (e.g. virsh Console), the installation process' graphics are converted to an ASCII equivalent like the following:

```
lqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqu Installing the base system tqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqk
x                                                                         x
x                                    94%                                  x
x                                                                         x
x Retrieving file 1 of 2                                           ..
x                                                                         x
mqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqj
```

Is there a way to disable that style and get the process to flow in a typical scrolling log style?

Answer (score 0):

Set `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=text` in the kernel command line e.g.

```
virt-install --boot,kernel=somekerne,initrd=someinitrd,kernel_args="DEBIAN_FRONTEND=text console=tty0 etc."
```

Comment: I've tried `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=text` and `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive`.  Both modes use the ASCII graphcs frames.

Comment: are you sure, that you placed `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=text` in the kernel command line? Because I'am using it for my install processes and it works.
Abort the installer, drop to the shell and look at `cat /proc/cmdline`

Comment: Hi, here is the script I am using:
`virt-install \        `
`--os-variant ubuntu16.04 \ `
`--name ${VM_NAME} \    `
`--vcpus 2 \   `
`--ram 4096 \  `
`--disk path=${STORAGE}${VM_NAME}.qcow2,size=20,bus=virtio \  `
`--nographics \      `
`--noautoconsole \    `
`--console pty,target_type=serial \      `
`--network network=VLAN${VLAN},model=virtio,mac=${MAC_ADDR} \ `
`--location ${ISO} \      `
`--initrd-inject ks.cfg \       `
`--boot kernel_args="DEBIAN_FRONTEND=text" \  `
`--extra-args="ks=file:/ks.cfg console=ttyS0"   `

Comment: Can you hit `Ctrl-C` during the installer and check if the parameter really reached the command line? Also start the virt-install with the `--debug` options, it gives you more details about what is happening

Comment: Can you add a "," to `--boot,kernel_args="DEBIAN_FRONTEND=text"`

Comment: If I add the comma, I get this error:
`virt-install: error: unrecognized arguments: --boot,kernel_args=DEBIAN_FRONTEND=text`